# HTTP server port number

Tags: node.js

If I create and HTTP server using nodejs like this:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

does it mean that if I use a web hosting service, the URL of the website will always need to contain somehow 8081 port? How would the URL look like?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would always need to the port number with requests, however if you use relative links this will not be such a problem.

```
<a href="/foo">Good idea</a>
<a href="http://yousite.com:8081">Questionable idea</a>
```

You may also look into reverse proxies and virtual hosts depending on your application.

Comment: I mean if you want to visit this website with name "somename", how would you know that you need to enter "www.somename.com:8081" instead of just "www.somename.com"? How can I make it send the request to the correct port without the need of the user to specify it?

Comment: Something (Apache for example) will have to listen on port 80 and do the redirect or you could use reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you expose a server using port 80 means http and / or via 443 means https. Your urls  don't need port. Other than that if you are using a different port then you can use ngnix or haproxy to expose them in 80 or 443. Without following this you will end up giving port to the urls